# ¿Como hacer que una tabla que se actualice al mismo tiempo que se hace un INSERT INTO a la base?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Estoy desarrollando una herramienta bastante simple, es para un Call Center funciona de la siguiente forma.

Es básicamente un "Ranking" de mejores vendedores, por medio de un formulario se ingresan las ventas a una base de datos y en la pagina reporte.php esta la tabla de la consulta los datos de las ventas se agrupan por vendedores y y ordenadas por totales.

el problema es que al ingresar una venta se debe de ir a la ventana de reporte.php y recargar la pagina para poder visualizar el la nueva venta. lo que quiero hacer es poder el ingreso de la nueva venta y que automáticamente en la ventana de reporte.php aparezca ya ingresada la venta sin tener que actualizar la pagina.

Comment: Automáticamente en programación hay poca cosa, habitualmente se tiene que programar para conseguir lo deseado. En tu caso, en el done del ajax, tienes que añadir el registro manualmente, por ejemplo con append de jquery. Ahora bien, puedes usar datatables o similar enlazado por ajax y entonces es automático porque otro lo programó previamente. Pero sin ver tu código es díficil de saber si es eso u otra cosa.

Comment: Esto me recuerda a todos los sitios web tipo red social, donde te van apareciendo las notificaciones "solas" a medida que llegan. Supongo que a eso es a lo que apuntas, que tu reporte se actualice solo, a medida que en la base se registren nuevas inserciones. Al modo tradicional, te tocaría dejar corriendo con Javascript un timer, que cada cierto tiempo consulte a la base de datos, y si encuentra cambios, recargue solo el reporte.

Comment: Si la idea es que tu usuario al ingresar una venta a través de tu aplicación y que se pueda ver reflejada, lo puedes hacer con una petición AJAX y manejando la respuesta para agregar los datos dinámicamente a través de la manipulación del DOM. Si tu quieres que la interface se actualice en base a la interacción de diversos usuarios con una única base de datos, entonces puedes usar [Web Sockets](https://medium.com/@dominik.t/what-are-web-sockets-what-about-rest-apis-b9c15fd72aac) que te permite no solo comunicarte del cliente al servidor, sino que sea bi-direccional, es decir, si algo se actual

Comment: ya estoy investigando un poco sobre Socket.io pero no tengo muy claro como hacer la integración en php

Comment: Y como podria hacerlo en ajax... por que bueno como les explicaba cuando se realiza el insert a la base tambien podria hacer que por medio de ajax se recargue la pagina de reporte.php (se me ocurre, no se bien como relizar esto)